# Requesting the user's file save BEFORE capturing screen?

Tags: java

Goodmorning, I've been trying to find out about this for a while but all the answers were linked to GUI and isn't something I've implemented in my code yet.

I have a very simple screen capture program that captures the current user's screen and stores it wherever the program is(In my case Desktop).

I would like to go give the user the option to pick the desired file or create a new file where to store this without have the need of popping out a GUI frame.

Is this possible? If yes, how may I achieve this?

Thanks in advance, if you need the source of the code I'll gladly post it :-)

Main Source:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    try{
        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Robot myRobot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage image = myRobot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(size));
        File save_patch = new File("ScreenCapture.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", save_patch);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Problem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you're using to create the `jpg` file.

Comment: I edited the main post with the code in the main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter file storage location: ");
String input = s.nextLine();
```

From here, you can grab the user's input, and add it to a `File` object.

```
if(file.isFile()) {
   File save_patch = new File(input);

   // Perform the save using this file object. 
}
```

**Edit**

In future, please try to phrase your questions a little more clearly.

> I would like to go give the user the option to pick the desired file or create a new file where to store this without have the need of popping out a GUI frame.

It's not the most concise requirement. You can use [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) to see how to allow the user to select a file.

Comment: Going to try it out in a moment. I don't think the System out is necessary considering I'm using this as a runnable JAR which just grabs the screen and captures it when clicked. Be back in a minute :-)

Comment: Not understanding where the file variable has come from though. Also, I just want want a popup allowing the user to pick a directory and save it

Comment: Sorry for not posting a clear question. Feel free to look at the above answer and post your comments on it

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a dialog for file choice. Read it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Might look like this (not tested):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    try{
        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Robot myRobot = new Robot();

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int ret = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

            BufferedImage image = myRobot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(size));
            File save_patch = new File(file.getName());
            ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", save_patch);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Problem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah okay understood! This popups the File chooser however doesn't ask the user to save the current file but instead tells the user to open a file. Like so: http://prntscr.com/3c148l. However thanks alot for the help, slowly getting there :)